# How to send Image from nodejs server to particular react-native mobile app client

Tags: node.js, client-server, react-native

I want to send image from node server to a particular react-native android app (client) specified by client_Id. App will have a facility to configure itself with some client_Id. I want to ensure the image will get delivered to the mobile with the specified client_Id. Suggest me which library/Modules/Protocols I should use.

[I Want to achieve something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCz90.png)

Comment: Well just send an HTTP request to your server including `client_id`. Return the url of the desired image (or image blob data if necessary).

Comment: Should I use mosquitto mqtt protocol?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in my opinion.

Comment: @ViktorSeč okay.

Comment: @ViktorSeč Here I want server should publish images frequently by specifying _clientId_'s. And an app user configured with its _clientId_ should receive the image if the _clientId_ of sent image  and the app's _clientId_ **matches**.

Comment: @ViktorSeč Can you elaborate yore first comment about using HTTP? That will be helpful.